# React Link redirects to proxied backend server

Tags: reactjs, routes, frontend

My React App proxies requests to the backend using

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

Inside package.json for dev purposes.

Somehow when I use a React Router Link component for redirection, the request is sometimes forwarded to the backend through the proxy instead of requesting the frontend page to be served. Why is this happening? Also, it's INCONSISTENT! Meaning sometimes it will do it, and sometimes it won't, despite clicking on the exact same Link component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!
I have removed the proxy setting from package.json altogether and added a setupProxy.js file inside my src folder containing the following:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(proxy.createProxyMiddleware("/api", { target: "http://localhost:3001/" }));
};
```

Comment: This simple works.

Answer (score -2):

Are you using identical routes on your front-end and back-end?
I would recommend you placing `API` in front of all your routes on the backend to avoid any inconsistencies.

so if your backend route was

> /users

change it to

> /api/users